# IBM DB2 table space full

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We have been having some issues with our DB2 instance. After some research, I ran the following query:

```
 select substr(tbsp_name,1,10) "Name", tbsp_utilization_percent "Used%", tbsp_free_pages "FreePages",

   tbsp_usable_Pages "UsablePages", tbsp_used_pages "UsedPages", tbsp_page_top "HWM",

   tbsp_auto_resize_Enabled "AutoResize 1=Yes", tbsp_max_size "MaxSizeBytes -1=ulimited",

   tbsp_last_resize_failed "ResizeFailed 1=Yes",

   tbsp_page_size "PgSize Bytes"

from SYSIBMADM.TBSP_UTILIZATION

where tbsp_type = 'DMS';
```

This returned a list of tablespaces with Used%. We have a few table spaces with 99.99% utilization. Unfortunately, we do not have a DBA, so it is up to me to resolve. I've done quite a bit of research but no luck just yet. How would one go about clearing up room in a tablespace?

Comment: Which operating-system runs the Db2-server? Give details.

Comment: If autoresize is enabled, it's normal for DMS tablespaces to be almost full -- they will be resized when necessary.

Comment: @mao Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Also, define what you mean by "some issues". Give error messages and error codes.  You can see these in the db2diag.log Check if the file system(s) on which those tablespaces reside are themselves full up .

Comment: @mustaccio auto-resize and automatic storage is enabled